# Importing Self Hosted Swagger Rest Api Client in Visual Studio instead of Azure Asset generate Unkown Folder and Object Name

Tags: visual-studio, swagger

### Problem:

When I try to import a self hosted swagger url (something like: https://api.net:443/swagger/docs/v1) I get an unknown folder created.

Accroding to this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-get-started/, the name of the azure project replaces the unknown in importing self hosted Swagger api metadata.

[image]

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this as well in a new console project server was an Owin self hosted but i used the file and it did nothing .. Second window did not show nor any files generated .

This Add rest api code seems very buggy or Azure only , no errors etc.

Comment: I Agree, this looks like azure only and requires manual intervention everytime a Client is generated.

I end up using Swagger codegen in a pre built Docker VM on my local machine. (When installing Docker also install Kitematic if you don't want to use command line stuff)

serach for swagger-generator. if you take the one of @swaggerapi, it will give you a rest API you can call upon (also using swagger) to generate the code in any language